# Ruby undefined method for nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am creating a simple method that compares numbers in an array.  There are rules, but I don't think that information is needed.

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  diff = 1
  p arr.length
  while true
    left = idx - diff
    right = idx + diff
    if (left >= 0) && (arr[left] > arr[idx])
      return left
    elsif (arr[right] > arr[idx]) && (right < arr.length)
      return right
    elsif (left < 0) && (right >= arr.length)
      return nil
    end

    diff += 1
  end
end
puts(nearest_larger([2,1,1,1], 0))
```

so when i change `(arr[right] > arr[idx]) && (right < arr.length)` to `(right < arr.length) && (arr[right] > arr[idx])` everything works fine.

why does the order matter here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order matters, because in a `&&` conditional statement, Ruby evaluates the left side first.  If the left side evaluates to `false`, it doesn't even bother to check the right side, because it already knows that the entire condition is `false`.

So, for `(arr[right] > arr[idx]) && (right < arr.length)`, it first evaluates:

`(arr[right] > arr[idx])`

This throws an error, because you're encountering a `nil` value, and there is no `>` method for `nil`.

But, for `(right < arr.length) && (arr[right] > arr[idx])`, it first evaluates:

`(right < arr.length)`

As soon as that returns `false`, it stops and calls the entire condition `false`, and doesn't ever evaluate the 2nd part; so there is no error.

Comment: its funny how easy an explanation makes things.  for some reason i guess i thought it would evaluate both before making a decision .... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a short-circuited condition.

```
(arr[right] > arr[idx])
```

still evaluates to `undefined method for nil class`, however it is not evaluated because the first part of the condition fails.